# Search through entire vimwiki

Tags: plugin-vimwiki

Is there a (built-in) way to search all vimwiki files for a certain pattern? I don't mean searching tags, but something akin to using grep on all the wiki files in the vimwiki directory.

If there is not a native vimwiki way, is there a way to do it without exiting the vimwiki (i.e a vim command of some sort)?

Comment: I don't know about vimwiki plugin or what you mean by vimwiki directory, i.e. whether it is the location the plugin is installed or where you store you own wiki files. But you could look into `:h :vimgrep`. It's fairly simple, and as you suggested, mostly alike `grep`

Comment: @klaus You should add that as an answer!

Comment: @Rich, I just talked about `:h :vimgrep` and `:h grep` in the answer because I actually didn't clearly understand what OP actually wanted. If s/he is actually using the plugin, he should be able to skim through the readme and help docs to be able to figure out what functionalities the plugin provides. If there is confusion, s/he should report it in the issue tracker of the plugin, not in a help forum. That's why I guessed the most basic way his requirement could have been interpreted.

Comment: @klaus I think that's a great answer! As I read it, the OP isn't too bothered about whether they use a plugin feature or a native Vim feature: they just want to get the job done. Upvoted!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vimwiki has a simple search included. You can run `:VimwikiSearch /pattern/` (the trailing slash is important). To go to the next hit run `:lnext` and `:lprevious` for the previous.

For more details you can look into the help pages `:h :VimwikiSearch`.

Comment: `:lfirst` and `:llast` might be needed cause these jumps are not cyclic.

Comment: `:lope` is useful for viewing the entire list of matches.

Answer (score 4):

### vimgrep

There is a command called `vimgrep` (see `:h :vimgrep`) that is a native grepping utility built into vim.

To search for a pattern in every wiki files in a directory, assuming the wiki files have `.wiki` extension, you would do:

```
:vimgrep /{pattern}/[g][j] path/to/directory/*.wiki
```

<sup>Check `:h :vimgrep` for info on the flags</sup>

With the above command vim will search the specified files with `.wiki` extension in the specified directory for the specified `{pattern}` and set the error list to the matches, i.e. load the quickfix window (see `:h quickfix`). You can move through the matches in the following ways:

- `:copen`  : To open the quickfix window
- `:cclose` : To close the quickfix window
- `:cnext`  : To jump to the next match
- `:cprev`  : To jump to the previous match
- `:cfirst`  : To jump to the first match
- `:clast`  : To jump to the last match

You can find info about the above keybindings and many more functionalities of quickfix in `:h quickfix`

There is a variant of quickfix window called `:h location-list`. It's a window local quickfix list, where a quickfix list is independent of a window/split. That is you can have multiple location-list but not more than one quickfix windows. So, you can create your workflow based on your needs.

In order to open quickfix and location-list windows right after a quickfix/location-list command has been issued, you can put the following in your `vimrc`:

```
augroup quickfix
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* nested cwindow
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost    l* nested lwindow
augroup END
```

### grep

You can also use the grepping utility provided by your system to fill up the quickfix list. The command is called, well, `:grep` (see `:h grep`). By default, the grep program to be used is set to use GNU grep and in a weird way that I couldn't figure out how to use it. But if you have some other grepping utility, which you should, like `silversearcher-ag` or `ripgrep-rg`, then you can set up the grep command in vim in the following way:

```
if executable('ag')
    set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor\ --hidden\ --ignore\ .git
endif
```

You can set up vim `:h grepprg` for `ripgrep-rg` in similar way. And it will also fill up your quickfix list the same way `vimgrep` does, and then you can jump among the matches with the same keybindings.

The equivalent of the `vimgrep` command mentioned above for `:h grep` would be:

```
:grep '{pattern}' path/to/directory/*.wiki
```